# .NETのIntptr構造体に関する質問です。

Tags: c#, .net

.NETのIntptr構造体に関する質問です。

C#でポインタを利用する際、Marshal.AllocHGlobalでメモリ領域を確保しMarshal.FreeHGlobalで確保した領域を解放しますが、Marshal.AllocHGlobalで確保された領域はガベージコレクションで自動的に解放されないのですか？

Comment: 過去の質問について、質問をしたまま放置せず、[解決したものについてはマーク](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)してください。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14200673969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

解放されません。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal
解説を読むうえで重要なキーワードは「マネージ」「アンマネージ」で、

- マネージ

.NET Framework の管理下にあって、オブジェクトが自動 gc されるもの。 [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) や [visualbasic](/questions/tagged/visualbasic) で `new` するとこっち。マネージメモリを Visual C/C++ native DLL に直接渡すことはできない。

- アンマネージ

.NET Framework の管理下にないもの。端的には Win32 Native なコードやメモリのこと。つまり Visual C/C++ で書いたコードや、直接使えるメモリのこと。アンマネージのほうが歴史的に古い存在なので、マネージコードからアンマネージコードを呼び出す際に「マーシャリング」することで、間接的にマネージコードからアンマネージメモリを使うことはできるようになっている（マーシャラの性能が高いかと問われると微妙かも）

この件、マニュアルにきっちり「アンマネージ」と明記されていますので gc 対象にはならないと読めます。すなわち、自分で `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` する必要があります。

Answer (score 2):

C#でポインタを利用する方法は複数あります。

例えば[`fixed`ステートメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement)を使用することで、指定したマネージメモリに対するGCを一時的に停止させ、ポインター操作を行うことができます。あくまで一時的に停止しているだけなので、`fixed`ステートメントを抜けた段階でGCは再開され、不要になったオブジェクトは自動的に解放されます。

[`Marshal.AllocHGlobal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=netframework-4.7.2)はポインターを扱う別の方法です。ちなみに名前に反して`GlobalAlloc`ではなく`LocalAlloc`を用いられています。`LocalAlloc`で確保したメモリーアドレスを取得することで、ポインター操作を行うことができます。こちらはGC管理外のメモリーを取得することが目的ですので、当然ながらGCが解放することはありません。

[IntPtr構造体](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.intptr?view=netframework-4.7.2)はあくまでメモリーアドレスを表現するだけであり、メモリー確保方法については関与していません。